# Script to read out Error log file from MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0, error-logging, error-log

I am searching for a PS script which reads out the SQL error log file. not the sql tables, just the file ERRORLOG where the log is stored. I googled it, but couldn't find the solution I want to have.

I need something similar to my script which reads out my eventviewer log.

```
get-eventlog -logname System -EntryType Error -newest 20
```

this displays the latest 20 errors..

So did someone else use that before? Or is there another approach which delivers the same information ?

If possible avoid PSv.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn’t specify  version this uses SMO for SQL 2012.  It’s just the three commands you need to hit a SQL Server and read the current ERRORLOG, part of a function I use regularly.

```
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" 
$serverObject = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server('YerServerNameHere')
$serverObject.ReadErrorLog()
```

Comment: yes this works, but I wanted to have a different solution if possible. To read out the file with get-content or something. Probably it's a too big process if the errorlog is already some mb..